# Login with devise and mobile_fu doesn't redirect correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

*Edit: I've solved the problem myself. If anyone has a better or more elegant solution, please post it here and I'll select as the answer.*

I', using jQuery Mobile and mobile_fu to set up a mobile view for a rails3 application.

Devise is used for authentication, and it works perfectly in the desktop view.

My problem is that after a successfully login in the mobile view, the application redirects again to the sign_in form when it should redirect to the root page. The sign in is correct, and if i just reload the page, then the redirection to root is correctly made. The sequence is as follows:

I enter the root page URL in the mobile device
As the user is not authenticated, devise redirects to the sign in page
I enter the credentials and hit the login button
The login is performed correctly, but the application redirects to the sign in page again
Hit reload in the mobile device, and then the application redirects to the root page with the user correctly authenticated

I've followed this instructions to set up devise with mobile fu, but using a 'mobile' format instead of 'iOS' format:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Make-Devise-work-with-other-formats-like-mobile,-iphone-and-ipad-%28Rails-specific%29

Any help will be appreciated, i've been working on this issue a couple of days and it's starting to drive me crazy :S
Thanks in advance!

I attach the request and response data both for mobile and desktop requests and responses when signing in:

> ## Desktop login
>
> ### Request
>
> POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:3000 User-Agent:
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101
>
> Firefox/7.0.1 Accept:
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding:
>
> gzip, deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Connection: keep-alive Referer: http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
>
> Cookie:
>   _PMG_session=BAh7CkkiCmZsYXNoBjoGRUZJQzolQWN0aW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7BjoKYWxlcnRJIkJOZWNlc2l0YXMgaW5pY2lhciBzZXNpw7NuIGNvbiB0dSBjdWVudGEgcGFyYSBwb2RlciBjb250aW51YXIuBjsAVAY6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7BjsHVEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOwBGIiViZjlkZDc4NzczMmFmMGViNjcyOWRkNzAxNWJhMzQ5YkkiEG1vYmlsZV92aWV3BjsARkZJIhN1c2VyX3JldHVybl90bwY7AEZJIgYvBjsARkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMWEyZW9oamFKT2tsWEZrbzZxc3lNenRhWTVEUk5XaHVUdm9iV3J3aFhFK1E9BjsARg%3D%3D--6623519d539757216a03d212a4e20647e8a5029c;
>   jstree_open=%231%2C%234%2C%235; jstree_load=
>
> ### Response
>
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found  Location: http://localhost:3000/ Content-Type:
>
> text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache X-UA-Compatible:
>
> IE=Edge X-Runtime: 1.650766 Server: WEBrick/1.3.1
>
> (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18) Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 08:58:24 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 88 Connection: Keep-Alive Set-Cookie:
>   _PMG_session=BAh7CkkiCmZsYXNoBjoGRUZJQzolQWN0aW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7BjoLbm90aWNlSSIoSGFzIGluaWNpYWRvIHNlc2nDs24gY29ycmVjdGFtZW50ZS4GOwBUBjoKQHVzZWRvOghTZXQGOgpAaGFzaHsASSIQbW9iaWxlX3ZpZXcGOwBGRkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMWEyZW9oamFKT2tsWEZrbzZxc3lNenRhWTVEUk5XaHVUdm9iV3J3aFhFK1E9BjsARkkiGXdhcmRlbi51c2VyLnVzZXIua2V5BjsAVFsISSIJVXNlcgY7AEZbBmkGSSIiJDJhJDEwJEZQL20vZ29KU2FGUFZ0bmRzb0VZeS4GOwBUSSIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZAY7AEYiJTA1NzI5YjFjOTMyZDdlMjk3YjEwYWQ5NWU3ZDJkZjYx--889ba65c483c3757b6aa47ffc2e187ac27a04dbe;
>   path=/; HttpOnly
>
> ## Mobile login
>
> ### Request
>
> POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: localhost:3000
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X;
>   en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341
>   Safari/528.16
>
> Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
>
> Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>
> Referer: http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.mobile
>
> Content-Length: 195
>
> Cookie: jstree_open=%231%2C%234%2C%235; jstree_load=;
>   _PMG_session=BAh7CkkiCmZsYXNoBjoGRUZJQzolQWN0aW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7BjoKYWxlcnRJIkJOZWNlc2l0YXMgaW5pY2lhciBzZXNpw7NuIGNvbiB0dSBjdWVudGEgcGFyYSBwb2RlciBjb250aW51YXIuBjsAVAY6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7BjsHVEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOwBGIiUwMjY0ZGFkODY2MGY3YmE5ZWY4NmQzYmRmODUyNDUxOEkiEG1vYmlsZV92aWV3BjsARlRJIhN1c2VyX3JldHVybl90bwY7AEZJIgYvBjsARkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTN5am1kaUhZcWpEZTAyclNNZ05ZNU5aZjA4bG5mamxCZHR6UmlVVHpkNFk9BjsARg%3D%3D--a6c9dbd6b27ac1b43193b4cba901b8862046dacf
>   Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> ### Response
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Etag: "22b69d3da00b31c705b66d95aa8a32de"
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
>
> X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
>
> X-Runtime: 1.317610
>
> Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18)
>
> Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 09:06:47 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 2915
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Set-Cookie:
>   _PMG_session=BAh7C0kiCmZsYXNoBjoGRUZJQzolQWN0aW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7BjoLbm90aWNlSSIoSGFzIGluaWNpYWRvIHNlc2nDs24gY29ycmVjdGFtZW50ZS4GOwBUBjoKQHVzZWRvOghTZXQGOgpAaGFzaHsASSIQbW9iaWxlX3ZpZXcGOwBGVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTN5am1kaUhZcWpEZTAyclNNZ05ZNU5aZjA4bG5mamxCZHR6UmlVVHpkNFk9BjsARkkiCWxpbmUGOwBGSSIGNQY7AFRJIhl3YXJkZW4udXNlci51c2VyLmtleQY7AFRbCEkiCVVzZXIGOwBGWwZpBkkiIiQyYSQxMCRGUC9tL2dvSlNhRlBWdG5kc29FWXkuBjsAVEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOwBGIiVhYWNkYzNlNjNhODU2ZWVjNmY1YmYzODEwNTk3NDA5Zg%3D%3D--31e22835ee0e428f80e0cf3f3ce5bd9fc8134d20;
>   path=/; HttpOnly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. Maybe I've should asked before to get the inspiration running :)

Apparently, Devise was not able to redirect correctly when the request format was not HTML. Unfortunately I relied on the format to serve different templates for a mobile device using mobile_fu, and [forcing the request format as devise wiki suggested](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Make-Devise-work-with-other-formats-like-mobile,-iphone-and-ipad-%28Rails-specific%29) order to get it running right with jquery mobile.

The solution I've found is an ugly one:
When the user makes the POST request to the devise controller -when is trying to authenticate- I force the html format instead of the mobile one. That way Devise is able to make the redirection correctly.

Code for *ApplicationController* class:

```
before_filter :set_mobile_format

def set_request_format
  if is_mobile_device? # this method is provided by mobile_fu
    if (devise_controller? && action_name == 'create' && request.method == ('POST'))
      request.format = :html
    else
      request.format = :mobile
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this can help anyone who runs into the same problem.

More elegant solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Override devise's SessionsController and give it mobile_fu:

```
class Users::SessionsController << Devise::SesssionsController
    has_mobile_fu
end
```

And in routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
```

This should work for mobile_fu 1.1, devise 2.1.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should, is to just follow the tutorial on Devise Wiki. I've solved the same problem by doing that just now!

There are, however, 2 different settings in my code:

1. I use `has_mobile_fu` (built-in with Mobile-Fu) instead of the custom before_filter `adjust_format_for_iphone`, you don't really need that before filter;
2. I use `.mobile.erb` instead of `.ios.erb`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do server-side user agent detection without changing the format of the request, take a look at [mobu](https://github.com/neighborland/mobu). The gem is similar to `mobile-fu` but without the format changes.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution is relatively straightforward and is configurable in the initializer.

tl;dr

When you use authenticate_user!, it calls the warden gem to test if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, the warden gem fails and invokes its failure_app.

When the request is xhr, devise by default sets the failure app to stop processing, so the AJAX request can be a nice, clean failure. However, you don't want that with jquery mobile. You want a new HTTP request to send you to the correct page.

/tl;dr

In your initializer (config/initializers/devise.rb), uncomment and change from true to false:

```
 config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

Enjoy!!